# SqlTasks.targets was not found

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am using code first and have updated a table.  Now I want to run `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` to update the model.  I have done this before and it worked for this specific project a couple of months ago, but now I get this cryptic error message:

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks
> .targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\Mi
> crosoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I use Visual Studio 2022 and have  SQL Server Data Tools installed (as I did some months ago).  How do I solve this?

(I also find it confusing that the error message linking to files for v11.0?  That is Visual Studio 2012 and have never been install on this PC)

**Edit 1:** Turns out the .sqlproj had this condition: `<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>`.  When removed it tried a different path for version 17.0 (VS 2022) which also did not exist.  I then just created that folder manually and copied some `SqlTasks.targets` files I found.  Then this error message was replaced with a different one.